# Android: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) on movie.draw

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, samsung-mobile

I am trying to display an animated gif in an ImageView using android Movie class in the onDraw method as follow:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (movieStart == 0) {
            movieStart = now;
        }
        movie = getMovieFromGif();
        if (movie != null && movie.duration() > 0) {
            try {
                int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % movie.duration());
                movie.setTime(relTime);

                float movie_height = convertDpToPixels(movie.height());
                float movie_width = convertDpToPixels(movie.width());

                float new_movie_height = movie_height;
                float new_movie_width = movie_width;
                float movie_ratio = movie_width / movie_height;

                if (new_movie_width > container_width) {
                    new_movie_width = container_width;
                    new_movie_height = new_movie_width / movie_ratio;
                }

                if (new_movie_height > container_height) {
                    new_movie_height = container_height;
                    new_movie_width = new_movie_height * movie_ratio;
                }

                float scale_x = container_width / new_movie_width;
                float scale_y = container_height / new_movie_height;

                scale_x = new_movie_width / (float) movie.width();
                scale_y = new_movie_height / (float) movie.height();

                canvas.scale(scale_x, scale_y);
                float x = 0;
                if ((float) this.getWidth() > new_movie_width) {
                    x = ((this.getWidth() - (movie.width() * scale_x)) / 2f)
                            / scale_x;
                }

                movie.draw(canvas, x, 0);
                this.invalidate();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("onDraw()", "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

Code runs fine on most devices but on Huawei Ascend P7 and Samsung galaxy a5, application crashes on movie.draw(canvas, x, 0) with exception:

> A/libc(23632): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1),
>   thread 23632

Any idea what is wrong with movie.draw on these devices?

UPDATED:
Following is the complete stack trace

> 04-29 12:09:24.979: D/Activity(18951): #2 setTransGradationModeColor
>   to true 
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951):
>   : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
>  04-29
>   12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version:
>   E031.24.02.07
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): Build
>   Date: 08/06/14 Wed
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): Local
>   Branch: rb1
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): Remote
>   Branch: 
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): Local Patches:
>   
>  04-29 12:09:25.049: I/Adreno-EGL(18951): Reconstruct Branch:
>   
>  04-29 12:09:25.079: D/OpenGLRenderer(18951): Enabling debug mode
>   0
>  04-29 12:09:25.109: D/skia(18951): streamToByte : Input agif
>   image larger than 30MB.
>  04-29 12:09:25.109: D/skia(18951):
>   streamToByte : Quram agif - length : 10473
>  04-29 12:09:25.109:
>   D/skia(18951): Wink AGIF Move Constructer End 9, totalTime : 2700
>   04-29 12:09:25.109: A/libc(18951): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at
>   0x00000000 (code=1), thread 18951 (com.android.gif)

Fatal signal error occurs after the execution of code movie.draw(), rest is the stack trace of execution of lines before movie.draw().

Comment: That appears to be a native null pointer de-reference, but you need to post the full native stack trace in order to untangle it, not just part of one line.

Comment: Updated the question with stack trace.

Comment: That is not a stack trace, but rather some log messages immediately preceding the stack trace.  Include the actual stack trace too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the android hardware acceleration:

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: Worked for me but not a viable solution because now every animation lags

Comment: Did you guys find a solution for this ? I'm also facing the Animation lagging issue if disabling the hardwardeAcceleration.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as what [Sultana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2468868/naheed-sultana), but surprisingly here's didn't work for me while this one did. it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29953117/3536839)
you disable the hardware accelerator only on this specific view you draw movie using this line.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```