# Android error signal 11 when a movie draws into a canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, gif

I'm developing an Android application in which I'm trying to display a GIF image.
For that I am using the Movie class and created a class GIFView that extends View. I getting a Movie instance from Movie.decodeFile method.

I am getting an error when Movie.draw(canvas) is called.

```
04-28 13:44:18.001: A/libc(24883): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 24883 (mple.channel002)
```

There is the concerned code :

```
    public void setGif(File gif)
    {
        movie = Movie.decodeFile(gif.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFCC3C6C);            

        if(movie != null)
        {
            if(movieStart == 0)
                movieStart = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            int duration = Math.max(movie.duration(), 1000);
            movie.setTime((int)(duration - ((android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - movieStart)%duration)));

            movie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);//TODO CRASH

            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I  create a GIFView in the main, call setGIF method above to give it the path and add it to the layout with FillParent parameter.
It works when I print this image in an ImageView.
Drawing a drawable in the canvas instead of the GIF works too. 
So the problem seems to deals with the Movie instance.

I used these links to make the GIFView 
http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-and-how-to-use-animated-gifs/

I also tried it this way but same error on movie.draw
[Info about the Movie class for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373718/info-about-the-movie-class-for-android)

EDIT1:
I do my tests on an Oppo Find 7a on Android 4.4.2 / snapdragon 801 / 2GB
Changing movie.draw(canvas, 10, 10) to movie.draw(canvas, 10f, 10f) doesn't change anything.

**EDIT2: 
I just tested on an old ZTE device with Android 2.3.5 and it worked..
So something is wrong when launching on Find7a device but I can't figure out what :(**

Comment: I do not know the solution, but I have some questions about the problem:
Do we know something about your runtime environment? Do you test it on Emulator, or phone?
I saw also that movie.draw waits for float instead of int. Did you tried with float numbers? like:
movie.draw(canvas, 10f, 10f);

Comment: I do my tests on an Oppo Find 7a on Android 4.4.2 / snapdragon 801 / 2GB and changing movie.draw(canvas, 10, 10) to movie.draw(canvas, 10f, 10f) doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the OS or the exact device. Please try it in Emulator if it is possible.
You can also search for device specific problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FINALLY! 
I found the answer, it appears that on some Android version or devices hardware acceleration needs to be disabled.
I just added this this to my manifest:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

More information on using enabling/disabling hardware acceleration can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution - you have to disable hardware accelerator only on this specific view you draw movie. Use next line:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Reference (view level)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling

Comment: Dude thanks. My heart skipped a beat when I ran my app in lollipop for the first time.